# Anyone have this Tower issue when creating GitHub Repo?

Tags: git, github, git-tower

Is anyone seeing this issue with Tower? When I try to Create GitHub Repository, if I enter anything in the "description" field, I get the following GitHub API Parse Error: "A response from the GitHub API could not be parsed. Please try to retrieve the resource again."

Tower then acts as if the repo was not created, but if I log into GitHub, I see it was.

If I don't enter anything into the "description" field, everything works as it should.

Comment: Please post the code you used.

Comment: Hey Reubano, thanks for the reply, but I am not using any code, I'm using Tower which is a GUI for GIT on Mac. Terminal way is working fine. I'm just wondering why Tower is having this issue, wasn't always like this. Could be a change that Tower made or maybe GitHub made and this is just something Tower needs to update. Or it could be just my computer. Trying to eliminate possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in current versions of Tower. However, as you already noticed, the repository gets created successfully - it's only the error message that's incorrect.
Until we fix this, the simple workaround is to clone the repository like any other repo with the standard "Clone Remote Repository" dialog.